# How can I go about optimising this long-winded script that's intended to basically reformat cell format? (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The use of this script is to:

1. tick cell F2 in the current tab so that all cells with `=QUERY` formula in another tab would be refreshed, and then the cells with `=ARRAYFORMULA` formula in the current tab would be refreshed,
2. then turn every formula cell in the current tab and change them into value cells,
3. then format certain value cells to be in NUMBER format with commas,
4. then go back to cell F2 and delete the checkbox.

As you can see, it's currently very long-winded. So I'm hoping to see how else I can go about optimizing it so that it's shorter and easier to manage.

Here's the current code I'm running -

```
function refresh() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('final result')
  sh.getRange('F1').setValue(!sh.getRange('F1').getValue())
}

function DataOutput() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('final result'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getDataRegion().activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('M5').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0')
  spreadsheet.getRange('R5').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('W5').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('F18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('I18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('W18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C74').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E74').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('F74').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('J74').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('X87').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B130').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H149').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('J149').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('L162').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M162').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('N162').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('L174').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M174').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('N174').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
```

ASKs:

What's with the need of `getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)`?

Because these cell range does not have a fixed range.

---

My (unsuccessful) work so far:

```
function refresh() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('final result');
sh.getRange('F1').setValue(!sh.getRange('F1').getValue());
}

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Auto Data Output')
.addItem('Auto Data Output (click here)','DataOutput')
.addToUi();
}

function setNumberFormat(sheet, ranges, format) {
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(ranges);
rangeList.setNumberFormat(format);
}

function DataOutput() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('final result');
 
sheet.getRange('F1').setValue('TRUE');

SpreadsheetApp.flush();

// Set number formats
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['E5', 'M5', 'R5', 'W5'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['B18:I18', 'Q18', 'W18'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['C74', 'E74', 'F74', 'J74'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['X87'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['B130'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['H149', 'J149'], '#,##0');
setNumberFormat(sheet, ['L162:N162', 'L174:N174'], '#,##0');

SpreadsheetApp.flush();

// Copy and clear data
sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
sheet.getRange('F1').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

Comment: When I see all those `.activate()`s I know its a recorded macro.  I suggest you learn how to use the Spreadsheet Service starting with [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: @Tedinoz I tried this and it didn't work - https://jpst.it/3gLZt

Comment: @Tedinoz When I run the script, seems like only the "copy all cells and paste as values" function worked. The "convert X cells to be #,##0" and to "delete checkbox in cell F2" didn't work.

Comment: Yes, once all the formula cells are changed to value cells, there would be no need to have the checkbox there anymore.

Comment: @Tedinoz Here's a sample sheet for reference - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCm455gp7Hq-gvy21hv6IuBQ1v7KV8boMzyzQY2yJf4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

> 1. tick cell F2 in the current tab so that all cells with =QUERY formula in another tab would be refreshed, and then the cells with =ARRAYFORMULA formula in the current tab would be refreshed,
> 2. then turn every formula cell in the current tab and change them into value cell,
> 3. then format certain value cells to be in NUMBER format with commas,
> 4. then go back to cell F2 and delete the checkbox.

In that order:

```js
function DataOutput() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('final result');

  // (1) toggle checkbox in cell F1 to refresh formulas
  const checkbox = sheet.getRange('F1');
  checkbox.setValue(!checkbox.getValue());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // (2) replace formulas with values
  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  dataRange.setValues(dataRange.getValues());

  // (3) set the number format in certain cells to '#,##0'
  sheet.getRangeList([
    'E5', 'M5', 'R5', 'W5',
    'B18:I18', 'Q18', 'W18',
    'C74', 'E74', 'F74', 'J74',
    'X87', 'B130', 'H149', 'J149',
    'L162:N162', 'L174:N174',
  ]).setNumberFormat('#,##0');

  // (4) remove checkbox from cell F1
  checkbox.clear();
}
```

> ASKs:
>
> What's with the need of getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)?

If you want to set the number format of cells at known fixed locations, you do not need that. Just add the ranges in the `sheet.getRangeList([...]` list above.

If the locations are variable, consider creating [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) that cover the contiguous ranges you want to format, and iterate those names like this:

```
  const namedRanges = [
    'MainPage', 'Boost', 'Video', 'Hashtag',
  ];
  const ranges = namedRanges.map(name => sheet.getRange(name));
  ranges.forEach(range => range.setNumberFormat('#,##0'))
```